# Mount HDFS Data on Alluxio

Tags: amazon-s3, hadoop, hdfs, alluxio

is it possible to mount HDFS data on Alluxio and have Alluxio copy/presist data onto s3 bucket?? or use Alluxio to copy data between HDFS and S3 (without storing data in Alluxio cache)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can mount multiple "under stores" to Alluxio (one hdfs and one S3)  and have data move between the two under stores either through explicit actions, or in some cases using some rules and automation to instigate the transfer of data (if you are using Alluxio enterprise).  It would end up storing the data in the Alluxio cache as it transfers, but you can certainly have data move.